# Xamarin.Forms run local html file in webview

Tags: c#, html, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I want to load a local HTML file that is in my Xamarin.Forms project. The file name is index.html. I searched and found a lot of people talking about this but none of the answers worked for me. This is where I am right now. You can see the HTML file on the side.

[Visual Studio Image #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toi64.png)

And this is my code for now

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initBrowser();
    }

    public void initBrowser()
    {

        var source = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        string url = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
        string TempUrl = Path.Combine(url, "index.html");
        source.BaseUrl = url;
        string html;
        try
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(TempUrl))
            {
                html = sr.ReadToEnd();
                source.Html = html;
            }

            browser.Source = source.Html;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: My problem is that I am not able to access my index.html in the android asset folder

> 10-28 15:13:23.111 I/mono-stdout(13979): Could not find a part of the
>   path "/file:/android_asset/AboutAssets.txt". Could not find a part of
>   the path "/file:/android_asset/index.html".

**EDIT 2: I found a way to solve my problem by just not trying to use HtmlWebViewSource. I just use the URI directly in the browser.Source**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PreuveXamarin
{
    public interface IBaseUrl { string Get(); }
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initBrowser();
        }

        public void initBrowser()
        {

            string path = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
            string url = Path.Combine(path, "index.html");

            browser.Source = url;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is covered explicitly in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#local-html-content

Comment: Yeah @Jason I tried using this and it worked for me but how can I do it from a local HTML file?

Comment: Did you read this part? "To display local content using a WebView, you'll need to open the HTML file like any other, then load the contents as a string into the Html property of an HtmlWebViewSource. For more information on opening files, see Working with Files."

Comment: Yeah, I am trying a bunch of things right now but none of them seems to work. I even tried code from other people on StackOverflow. I have the IBaseUrl interface and have implemented it in my android app.I'm able to retrieve the file:///android_asset/ but can't get my index.html file to run